# How can I implement Aztec-barcode with iText 7 or 5 using pdfHtml plugin?

Tags: java, itext, aztec-barcode

I would like to implement Aztec-barcode in my java code, but the problem is, that it seems based on the API doc that they don't have any implementation at iText.

I have tried with iText7 pdfHtml plugin.

Any help would be welcome!

Comment: please provide a [minimal reproducaple example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: this feature has been added to our product backlog (disclaimer: iText Technical Product Developer here), but in all honesty, we haven't gotten any customer requests about this feature, so it may take a while to get implemented.

having said that. you can use a third party library to generate your barcode, and then just embed the image by using iText.